# Why SSDs very slow in Virtual Machine when compared to speed in Host machine?

Tags: ssd, virtual-machine, hyper-v, hyper-v-manager

I have a Windows server 2012 R2 Host PC. There is a Windows
10 Hyper V instance running in it. This Hyper V instance has 2 HDD's and 1 SSD
, all 3 connected directly to the VM by creating an SCSCI controller and
selecting the drives.

**HDD 1:** Seagate Exos 7E2 Enterprise internal 1TB SATA ST1000NM0008

**HDD 2:** Seagate Constellation ES.3-ST1000NM0033

**SSD:** Kingston 120GB UV400 SSD

Data transfer speed between two HDD’s attached to this Hyper
V instance is 180MB/s. Data Transfer from the SSD to any one of the HDD is
initially 400MB/s or above, after 30-35% transfer speed is 170-180MB/s.

But transfer speed from any one of the HDD to SSD, is
initially 200MB/s. After transfer completion of 40-50% the transfer speed drops
down to 30-40MB/s or lower. When all 3 (2 HDD's and 1 SSD) is allocated and
used in Host PC (VM is off), transfer from any of the HDD to SSD is in the
range of 250-300 MB/s constant without any drop in transfer speeds.

**What I have tried:**

1. I have updated Windows Server 2012 R2 Host
   PC to the latest version available (KB5018474) but the SSD problem was not
   solved in the Hyper V instance running inside it.
2. Also tried testing the SSD and HDD in Hyper V
   instance running in Windows 10 Host (KB5014023) and the results were no
   different.
3. I have also mounted these disks to
   different SCSI controllers as well, but still getting the same transfer speed
   when copying files from HDD to SSD.

The problem with
SSD’s emerging only when it is used in Hyper V (No problem when directly
attached to Host PC). Are there any obvious settings in Hyper V that might be
causing this problem?

Comment: Can you check/share the cache setting tab of the SSD in Device Manager of the host *and* the VM?

Comment: I have both Hyper-V VMs and VMware VMs on fast SSD drives and the VM performance is excellent. Perhaps spin up and try a different VM.